# Prevent CSRF attack in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: antiforgerytoken

I have 2 applications. One application performs form submit(http post) to other application(both are mvc applications separately hosted under same site). Form submit is legacy javascript submit. Preparing hidden variables as htmlstring in controller and posting it by Response.write from controller. Now, how do I implement antiforgery token logic for this scenario. Is it possible to call antiforgerytoken() in controller. Pls suggest.

Comment: If you are using java, pls check if this link is useful to u :https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-flash-attributes

Comment: What language and framework/cms do these applications use ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "mvc application" means that ASP.NET MVC application.

There is a plenty of different CSRF prevention approach such as via Form body, custom header or cookie. In you situation  using Cookie is going to solve your problem but you need to figure out cookie sharing across two ASP.NET application. ASP.NET supports cookie sharing with some configuration, details is here http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html

In the basics;

1. Generate CSRF token.
2. Set this token to the cookie as well ass the form body with hidden value.
3. Client submits the form.
4. Since both application is under the same domain, our csrf token cookie will be reached to the 2nd application.
5. Checkout the cookie and form body has same token. If there is not CSRF attacks  those value should be the same.

Comment: For the first 2 steps, is it possible to use inbuilt method antiforgery token in controller. Or should i manually write coding with some hashing algorithms